# Type 1 grammar for all even powers of terminal character 'a'.

Tags: formal-languages

I'm new to formal languages. I'm stuck with the following question, and can't seem to find a solution to it.

I need a type 1 grammar for:

$$\{a^i \mid i=2j \text{ for some } j\ge0\}$$

I'm aware that type 1 grammar is a context-sensitive grammar where all productions are of type

$$aCb\to acb\;.$$

I can't find how to get a grammar for even powers of $a$.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I've edited your question to consistently ask for a grammar for even powers of $a$ (you had the condition $i = 2^j$, notably different from $i = 2j$, in your target set). Hopefully, this is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that.

Comment: @borntocode I am a bit puzzled by your sentence "I'm aware that type 1 grammar is a context-sensitive grammar where all productions are of type $aCb \to acb$". Type-1 grammars are usually [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) as context-sensitive grammars, so is your definition a different one?

Comment: No, I meant the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural idea is to use a production of the form $A\to aAa$ that generates a pair of $a$’s at a time; that clearly has the right form. We also need to be able to stop generating; $A\to aa$ does the trick, but you may need to convince yourself that it has the right form.

In a Type $1$ grammar with $\Sigma$ as its set of terminal symbols and $N$ as its set of non-terminal symbols the productions (with one exception) must be of the form $\alpha X\beta\to\alpha\gamma\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta\in(\Sigma\cup N)^*$, $X\in N$, and $\gamma\in(\Sigma\cup N)^+$. $A\to aa$ is of that form, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ empty strings, $X=A$, and $\gamma=aa$. Thus, the grammar with productions

$$\begin{align*}
&A\to aAa\\
&A\to aa
\end{align*}$$

and initial symbol $A$ almost works: *almost*, because it doesn’t generate the empty word, which **is** in the language. This is where the exception that I mentioned comes in. The exception is that in order to be able to generate the empty word, we also allow $S\to\lambda$, where $S$ is the initial symbol, provided that there is no production with $S$ on the righthand side. A grammar that meets these conditions is:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to\lambda\\
&S\to A\\
&A\to aAa\\
&A\to aa
\end{align*}$$

(You can replace $A\to aAa$ with $A\to aaA$ or $A\to Aaa$, if you prefer.)

Comment: Ah, now I see. Very clever use of S→λ. Thank you.

Comment: @BornToCode: You’re welcome. (By the way, the set of $a^k$ such that $k$ is a power of $2$ is a context sensitive language, but coming up with a context sensitive grammar for it is **much** harder.)

Comment: M.Scott: Oh really? I would like to know how. Do you have any thoughts on that. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @BornToCode: I’ve not actually done it. I can write a [monotonic grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar) that generates the language, and there’s a rather lengthy algorithm to convert a monotonic grammar to a context sensitive grammar, but I’ve not actually carried out the conversion.

Comment: Oh, I see. Seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is $(a^2)^*$. Therefore it is a regular language and as such it can be generated by a Type 3 grammar, which mimics the behavior of the minimal automaton of the language. In your case
\begin{align}
  S &\to aT \\
  T &\to aS \\
  S &\to 1
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the solution. Can you provide me any insight on the following modification of the above problem. If i= 2^j, j>=0. Then what would be the grammar?